# Required Mailboxes

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces, mailbox

Regarding this answer https://serverfault.com/a/134814

What are the minimal mailboxes required for a domain?

Currently I only specify these mailboxes:

root@
webmaster@
postmaster@
admin@
domain@
domains@
hostmaster@
bounce@
returnpath@
return-path@

Am I missing some, what's the best RFC resource for listing them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see RFC 2142 for suggestion. (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt)

[image]